# Read write object to JSON

Tags: c#, json, object

If I have a class `Contact`:

```
   public class Contact
   {
    public Contact()
    {

    }

    public int ID { get; set;}
    public string firstName { get; set;}
    public string lastName { get; set;}

    }
```

in my code I instantiate 5 different `Contact` objects and their specific properties and then put them into a `List<Contact>`.

My questions:

- How can I convert the `List<Contact>` to JSON?
- How can I read the JSON back to a `List<Contact>`?
- How can I read from JSON the contact with ID 123 and instantiate a `Contact` object out of it so I have all the properties?

Much appreciated your help!
Thanks!

P.S. The JSON will look something like this ?:

```
{
    contacts:{
        contact:[
            {
                id:123,
                firstname:'jhon',
                lastname:'smith'
            },
            {
                id:1234,
                firstname:'robert',
                lastname:'smith'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: This online tool: http://www.thomasfrank.se/xml_to_json.html :). Well I am kinda new to JSON. I know how to make an XML out of it but no JSON. I was thinking to make XML than convert that to JSON but I think and hope that there is a way that will do it direct to JSON avoiding unnecesary XML work.

Comment: Here is an example of sending a list of objects using JSON http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/pini_dayan/archive/2009/03/12/convert-objects-to-json-in-c-using-javascriptserializer.aspx

Comment: I was thinking to try JavaScriptSerializer .. is this the proper way ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json+c%23

Comment: Thanks @cshemby: Seams to be what I am looking for.

Comment: The link I sent you uses just that. There is also the reverse of that to read the JSON here http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/79435/Deserialize-JSON-with-C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search of the web reveals suggestions for the JavaScriptSerializer

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = 
new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(YOUR CLASS HERE);
```

I suggest you give it a try.

Source [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/pini_dayan/archive/2009/03/12/convert-objects-to-json-in-c-using-javascriptserializer.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at JSON.NET (OSS third party library) or DataContractJsonSerializer (available in frameworks from 3.5 onward).